# How to prevent duplicate code when checking multiple checkbox statuses in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a form of checkboxes that displays images when the property "checked" is true or false. The first checkbox is now functional, but it's unclear to me how I can reduce the amount of code needed since each checkbox does essentially the same thing.

The working function that I have to display an image is written below:

```
const pepperoniCheckbox = document.getElementById("pepperoniCheckbox");
const pepperoniImage = document.getElementById("pepperoni-image");

document.getElementById("pepperoniCheckbox").onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    pepperoniImage.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    pepperoniImage.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
};
```

The HTML for the images and checkboxes is here as well:

```
<div class="ingredients-boxes" style="padding-top: 200px">
  <input type="checkbox" value="pepperoni" id="pepperoniCheckbox" />
  <label for="pepperoni"> Pepperoni </label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="olives" id="olivesCheckbox" />
  <label for="olives"> Olives </label>
</div>
<main>
  <div class="pizza-holder">
    <img class="pizza" src="pizza-hut-crust-pan-pizza-food-delivery-pizza.jpg" />
    <img class="pizza pepperoni" id="pepperoni-image" src="pepperoni-transparent.png" />
  </div>
</main>
```

I'm sure there is a way to duplicate this effect for the future checkboxes and content I add but I cannot wrap my head around it. I think that each checkbox needs to have an onclick event where they all point to the same function instead of putting the function on each checkbox variable like I have done above.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this, but a simple one is this:

Create a JS function that takes an element as an option and uses it to build the id (assuming you keep consistent naming conventions):

```
function isChecked(e) {
  if (e.checked) {
    document.getElementById(e.value + '-image').style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(e.value + '-image').style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

Then in your HTML, add an `onclick` to each element:

`<input type="checkbox" value="pepperoni" id="pepperoniCheckbox" onclick="isChecked(this);"/>`

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

You can use what's called **event delegation** with **Element.prototype.matches** and **event.target**.

Working Example:

(*note: I removed the padding from the parent div to better fit the demo*)

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".ingredients-boxes");

parent.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
const element = event.target;

if(element.matches("input[type='checkbox']")) {
const image = document.querySelector("#" + element.value + "-image");
  if (element.checked) {
    image.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    image.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
});
```

```html
<div class="ingredients-boxes">
  <input type="checkbox" value="pepperoni" id="pepperoniCheckbox" />
  <label for="pepperoni"> Pepperoni </label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="olives" id="olivesCheckbox" />
  <label for="olives"> Olives </label>
</div>
<main>
  <div class="pizza-holder">
    <img class="pizza" src="pizza-hut-crust-pan-pizza-food-delivery-pizza.jpg" />
    <img class="pizza pepperoni" id="pepperoni-image" src="pepperoni-transparent.png" />
    <img class="pizza olives" id="olives-image" src="pepperoni-transparent.png" />
  </div>
</main>
```

### Explanation:

**Event Delegation** adds an *Event Listener* to the **Parent** element.

This *event listener* watches for an event. When an event occurs it then checks to see which of the **child** elements caused the event.

The active element is available in `event.target`.

```
parent.addEventListener(function(event) {
const element = event.target;

});
```

We can check if that element is what we're looking for by using the `matches` method of **Element.prototype**

For instance, in your case, we're looking for **checkboxes**.

```
parent.addEventListener(function(event) {
const element = event.target;

if(element.matches("input[type='checkbox']")) {
   // do something
}

});
```

---

The important thing when using Event Delegation is that you keep the same exact naming conventions for items that you would like to manipulate.

In your case the **ID** of the image is always `element.value + "-image"`

Because of that we can look up the element and adjust its `visibility` inside the **event listener**.

```
const image = document.querySelector("#" + element.value + "-image");
  if (element.checked) {
    image.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    image.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

---

### Full code:

```
const parent = document.querySelector(".ingredients-boxes");

parent.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
const element = event.target;

if(element.matches("input[type='checkbox']")) {
const image = document.querySelector("#" + element.value + "-image");
  if (element.checked) {
    image.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    image.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
});
```

---

### Suggestions:

- Give all of your *topping* images a class so that they load `hidden`.
- Cache the image element so you don't have to search the DOM every time a checkbox is clicked.

**Topping Class - Initially Hidden Example:**

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".ingredients-boxes");

parent.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
const element = event.target;

if(element.matches("input[type='checkbox']")) {
const image = document.querySelector("#" + element.value + "-image");
  if (element.checked) {
    image.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    image.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
});
```

```css
.topping {
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="ingredients-boxes">
  <input type="checkbox" value="pepperoni" id="pepperoniCheckbox" />
  <label for="pepperoni"> Pepperoni </label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="olives" id="olivesCheckbox" />
  <label for="olives"> Olives </label>
</div>
<main>
  <div class="pizza-holder">
    <img class="pizza" src="pizza-hut-crust-pan-pizza-food-delivery-pizza.jpg" />
    <img class="pizza pepperoni topping" id="pepperoni-image" src="pepperoni-transparent.png" />
    <img class="pizza olives topping" id="olives-image" src="pepperoni-transparent.png" />
  </div>
</main>
```

**Caching Example:**

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".ingredients-boxes");

parent.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
if(!this.cache) {
 this.cache = {};
}

const element = event.target;

if(element.matches("input[type='checkbox']")) {
const topping = element.value;
let image = this.cache[topping];

if(!image) {
 image = 
 this.cache[topping] = 
 document.querySelector("#" + element.value + "-image");
}

  if (element.checked) {
    image.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    image.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

}
});
```

```css
.topping {
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="ingredients-boxes">
  <input type="checkbox" value="pepperoni" id="pepperoniCheckbox" />
  <label for="pepperoni"> Pepperoni </label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="olives" id="olivesCheckbox" />
  <label for="olives"> Olives </label>
</div>
<main>
  <div class="pizza-holder">
    <img class="pizza" src="pizza-hut-crust-pan-pizza-food-delivery-pizza.jpg" />
    <img class="pizza pepperoni topping" id="pepperoni-image" src="pepperoni-transparent.png" />
    <img class="pizza olives topping" id="olives-image" src="pepperoni-transparent.png" />
  </div>
</main>
```